# How do i make my code continue to run even after an error?

Tags: python

The languaged used for this code is python. So basically the cmd its having trouble replying to is a highlow cmd, this code is suppose to click high or low depend if its above or lower than the number given. I would like it to continue to run the code even if it does run into an error. If you want to you can contact me on my discord: UnPurgable#6969
This is my Code:

```
from requests import post, get
from utils.logger import register
from time import sleep
from json import loads

import os 
path = 'Y:\\Files\\'
listing = os.listdir(path)
try:
for infile in listing:
    try:
        if infile.startswith("ABC"):
            with open(infile,"r") as fo
                for line in fo:
                    if line.startswith("REVIEW"):
                        print infile
    except:
        pass

def highlow(log, token, channel_id, timeout, logging):
    request = post(f"https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/{channel_id}/messages", headers={"authorization": token}, data={"content": "pls hl"})
    
    if request.status_code != 200 and logging["warning"]:
        register(log, "WARNING", f"Failed to send command `pls highlow`. Status code: {request.status_code} (expected 200). Aborting command.")
        return
    
    if logging["debug"]:
        register(log, "DEBUG", "Successfully sent command `pls highlow`.")
    
    latest_message = None
    
    sleep(2)
    
    for _ in range(0, timeout):
        sleep(1)
        
        request = get(f"https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/{channel_id}/messages", headers={"authorization": token})
        
        if request.status_code != 200:
            continue

        latest_message = loads(request.text)[0]
        
        if latest_message["author"]["id"] == "270904126974590976" and logging["debug"]:
            register(log, "DEBUG", "Got Dank Memer's response to command `pls highlow`.")
            break
        else:
            continue
       
    if (latest_message is None or latest_message["author"]["id"] != "270904126974590976") and logging["warning"]:
        register(log, "WARNING", f"Timeout exceeded for response from Dank Memer ({timeout} second(s)). Aborting command.")
        return
    
    number = int(latest_message["embeds"][0]["description"].split("**")[-2])
      
    data = {
        "application_id": 270904126974590976,
        "channel_id": channel_id,
        "type": 3,
        "data": {
            "component_type": 2,
            "custom_id": latest_message["components"][0]["components"][0]["custom_id"] if number > 50 else latest_message["components"][0]["components"][2]["custom_id"] if number < 50 else latest_message["components"][0]["components"][1]["custom_id"]
        },
        "guild_id": latest_message["message_reference"]["guild_id"],
        "message_flags": 0,
        "message_id": latest_message["id"]
    }
    
    request = post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions", headers={"authorization": token}, json=data)
    
    if (request.status_code == 200 or request.status_code == 204) and logging["debug"]:
        register(log, "DEBUG", "Successfully interacted with button on Dank Memer's response to command `pls highlow`.")
    elif logging["warning"]:
        register(log, "WARNING", f"Failed to interact with button on Dank Memer's response to command `pls highlow`. Status code: {request.status_code} (expected 200 or 204).")
```

This is the error i get:

```
File "C:\Users\Dung\Desktop\grank-2\src\main.py", line 60, in <module>
    highlow(log, token, channel_id, config["cooldowns"]["timeout"], config["logging"])
  File "C:\Users\Dung\Desktop\grank-2\src\scripts\highlow.py", line 40, in highlow
    number = int(latest_message["embeds"][0]["description"].split("**")[-2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: not sure why it glitched and seperated the code

Comment: You didn't put a newline after the three back ticks.

Comment: Well... did you try to figure out which `list index is out of range`? Do you understand the issue? When it occurs, is it actually okay to proceed? What should the program do after that point? In particular, what should the value of `number` be going forward?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`List index out of range` means you're trying to access an element that isn't in the list.

From this, I'd say there's only 1 element in `latest_message["embeds"][0]["description"].split("**")`, meaning `latest_message["embeds"][0]["description"].split("**")[-**1**]` exists, but `latest_message["embeds"][0]["description"].split("**")[-**2**]` does not.

Comment: this error only happens once every 3 hours depending on the bot that gives the number, im not exactly sure what would happen even if i removed it, and how do i just make it so my code continues to run even after facing an error

Comment: Well yes, you can ignore it with a try / except condition, but it's poor form to just ignore the error. Determine why there might not be 2 elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the message you got from Dank Memer is actually a cooldown message, thus meaning the code tries to get a value that isn't there. Like [csjh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16139086/csjh) said, just use a try and except block to make the code carry on executing if it ever encounters that error.